# new migrations are generated but are not applied to Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, migration, database-migration

I have 2 migrations created and already applied to db, but my new migration (just inserts) is not being applied when release and up to the server.

I'm running the ExecuteSqlFilesWithinMigrationsFolder () from DbMigrationBase

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q3br.png

```
    public partial class testando123 :DbMigrationBase {
        public override void Up() {
            ExecuteSqlFilesWithinMigrationsFolder(@"201905282356499_testando123\up");
        }

        public override void Down() { }
    }
```

Comment: migrations should be applied automatically when the context's initialization strategy is run. Which one do you use, or did you create a new initializer?

Answer (score -1):

In packege manger console write this command 
update-database

Comment: Hey there, i need this not in local server, i need in release mode.